# CodeIgniter - Why JQuery won't update a form_dropdown

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have two dropdowns - Group and Subgroup. If the Group is changed then I want to update the Subgroup with a new list of items that are subs of the new Group.

Here is my code for the dropdowns:

```
<div  id="inp_p_group"class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Select Group:</label>
   <div class="controls">
    <?php
    $p_groups = array();
    $p_groups['-1'] = 'no selection';
    foreach ($groups->result() as $g_row){
        $p_groups[$g_row->tbl_group_id] = $g_row->vch_group_name;
    }
    echo form_dropdown('p_groups', $p_groups, $row->fk_group_id, 'style="width: 140px; font-size: 13px" id="p_groups"'); 
    ?>
   </div>
 </div>       

 <div  id="inp_p_groupsub"class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Select Sub Group:</label>
   <div class="controls">
   <?php
     $p_groupsub = array();
     $p_groupsub['-1'] = 'no selection';
     foreach ($sub_groups->result() as $s_row){
        $p_groupsub[$s_row->tbl_group_sub_id] = $s_row->vch_sub_name;
     }
     echo form_dropdown('p_groupsub', $p_groupsub, $row->fk_group_sub_id, 'style="width: 140px; font-size: 13px" id="p_groupsub"'); 
   ?>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And this is my JScript code

```
$('#p_groups').change(function() {
    var select = document.getElementById("p_groups");
    var myvalue= $.trim(select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
    // now populate the Sub Group selector with the children of the selected Group
    group_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    // make call to function to get the sub-group data
    $.post(
        "../product_controller/get_subgroup_json",// function call
        {'gid' : group_id},                         // function data
        function (retval) {                         // callback function
            //var sub_list = document.getElementById("p_groupsub");
            var sub_list = $('#p_groupsub')[0];
            sub_list.options.length = 0; // this removes existing options
            $.each(retval, function(index, element) {
                // create an Option object
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                // Add an Option object to Drop Down/List Box
                sub_list.options.add(opt);
                // Assign text and value to Option object
                opt.value = index;
                opt.text = element;
            });
        }, // end callback
        "json"
        ); // end post
}); // end p_groups-change function
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is not working, any help greatly appreciated.

G.

UPDATE
I've been lookinginto this further and I use the same JS in another part of the site to do the same thing. In both places I call the function

```
 "../product_controller/get_subgroup_json"
```

to return a list of sub-groups.

Wehn I call it from the code that is working the POST header looks like this

```
 ../index.php/product_controller/get_subgroup_json?gid=12
```

but when I call it from the code that is not working, the POST looks like:

```
../index.php/product_controller/product_controller/get_subgroup_json?gid=12
```

The JS is identical in both cases, so I don't know where the extra 'product_controller/' is coming form.

G.

Comment: Put your php code result (html) and js in a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The code uses Bootstrap 2.0. Wil this work in jsfiddle? I have no experience of using it.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it working in jsfiddle - here: http://jsfiddle.net/unplugngo/ab9gqxLt/

Comment: don't put your php in jsfiddle… put the html created by your php (view source on your browser)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've done that.

Comment: Did you save/update it ?

Comment: Yes, it has been updated but I don't see how it will work in jsfiddle - it needs to make a call to the database in order to get the new subgroup data when the group dropdown selection changes.

Comment: run it on your server (wamp, easyphp, mamp or your hosting…) save the html and paste it…

Comment: That's what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in the call to the function that fetches the data for the subgroup dropdown, which looks like this:

```
 $.post(
    "../product_controller/get_subgroup_json",  // function call
```

Because the view is called from product_controller, this routing is implicit in any further function calls, so the call should be:

```
 $.post(
    "../get_subgroup_json",  // function call
```

I think it's really weird that the URI didn't cause an error somewhere, so I'd appreciate if anyone has any ideas on the matter to give me some feedback.

Thanks again for looking.

U.